# Mirror duplicated canvas in a particular manner in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation, transform, mirror

There is a square shaped canvas with contents drawn dynamically by Javascript (not an external image file!) having four corners, i.e. `a` (top left), `b` (top right), `c` (bottom left), and `d` (bottom right). I want to have a script that creates a new canvas which is made of four duplicated instances of the first canvas:

```
ab
cd
```

mirrored in a particular manner (butterfly):

```
dccd
baab
baab
dccd
```

and in a rotating manner (pinwheel):

```
dcbd
baac
caab
dbcd
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the first question regarding the butterfly manner:

```
var sid=$("source").toDataURL("image/png"),dcc=$("destination").getContext('2d'),di=new Image,dim=$("source").offsetWidth;
$("destination").width=(dim*2);$("destination").height=(dim*2);di.onload=function(){
dcc.drawImage(di,dim,dim,dim,dim);
dcc.scale(-1,-1);dcc.drawImage(di,0,0,dim*-1,dim*-1);
dcc.scale(-1,1);dcc.drawImage(di,dim,0,dim*1,dim*-1);
dcc.scale(-1,-1);dcc.drawImage(di,0,dim,dim*-1,dim*1);
};di.src=sid;
```

However, the pinwheel manner is not resolved yet... Suggestions are much appreciated here!